# How can I checkout a tree given a SHA from Github?

Tags: git, github

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and the Github Extension for Visual Studio 2013.

I could clone a project on Github successfully from the clone URL.

I would like to checkout some commits from a user to continue his work (he hasn't created a pull request and he remains unresponsive). I understand this is called a `tree` that can be identified either by name or a SHA.

I tried with `git checkout [sha]` and `git checkout [name_of_tree]` without success. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: When you say ‘*tree*’, do you mean branch?

Comment: I'm sorry - I mean the commits of a given user, which Github seems to be calling a "tree". For example: https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/pull/166/commits

Comment: No mention of a ‘tree’ there. Do you mean a repository? That page shows a *pull request*, with three *commits*, in a *branch* called `feature/UserTokenReplacement`. Did you clone `chucknorris/roundhouse` or `guilhermeando/roundhouse`?

Comment: @Biffen http://www.gitguys.com/topics/git-object-tree/

Comment: @DanBerindei Yes. Still not sure what OP means by ‘tree’, though.

Comment: @Biffen I think he means just a commit object, because trees are a bit more generic but nothing else on that page fits.

Comment: @DanBerindei Could be. But then what would `[name_of_tree]` be?

Comment: @Biffen sounds like something from a git man page...

Comment: @user4811392, where did you go? We're lost without you!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I'm starting to understand. feature/UserTokenReplacement is a branch, not a "tree". I call it a tree because, when I go into a specific commit ("Browse the repository at this point in history"), I see the word "tree": https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/tree/072b442a63aa8322e9811d96a3f1840406132509

Comment: So I will try to clone that repository, now that I understand it's actually a branch and not a "tree". Thank You!